# A javafx program within another javafx Program

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, module

I would like to know what is the right approach to building a program within another program. I've finished building Project A(calendar application) with javafx. It looks up events for any days that have events saved to them. I want to embed this program as a feature inside another javafx program. I've been looking up modules and not sure if thats the right approach to accessing the specific files i need to use. I also want an fxml file in project B.(Library Management System), to be able to <"include"> another fxml file by accessing it from project A. Is this possible and if so am I supposed
to copy all the files from A and put them in B or do more research on using modules to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by exporting the old project as a jar and putting it in my other project which accessed the files I needed it to access. I hope this is a good approach but it works in the end at least.

Comment: it told me i have a wait period I have 7 hours left